# I am curious about the internal implementation logic of trailing stop through 'strategy.exit()'

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to use trailing stops in pinescript.
But trailing stop differs greatly from actual trading, and I am curious as to whether this can be minimized.

I am curious about the internal logic, flow, and structure of how trailing stops are handled within pinescript.

Answer (score 0):

Pine Script uses the `strategy.exit` function to implement trailing stops. When you set a trailing stop value, it monitors the price movement and adjusts the stop level accordingly. The internal logic involves checking the current price against the highest/lowest price reached, and if the price drops below a certain percentage from the highest/lowest, the trailing stop is triggered.

The key to understanding and minimizing discrepancies lies in market conditions and the granularity of the data you're working with. In volatile markets or with lower timeframes, the price can fluctuate more rapidly, leading to variations in the execution of trailing stops.